# The linux way of structuring makefiles / deployment - development?

Tags: c, linux

I have a question: Many repositories do not include libraries that have debug symbols in them. So that means I have to install them myself, and usually they install into different directories than the libraries I would get from my distribution. 
Obviously(?) I want to run my actual application with stripped, optimized libraries, however now my makefiles are written so they work with custom compiled libraries (which include the dbg symbols)...example:

-I/usr/local/include/whatever is now the correct path, but on deployment I think I will need -I/usr/include/whatever

This is just a simple example, but it shows how everything is different on my development machine and on my deployment machine. Surely there must be some solution people have come up with to combat this? Can you help? (other than obvious things like writing if's into the makefile, that is ugly and errorprone)

I just don't understand how anyone can work like this. The only solution is to compile everything always myself..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A debug or release build is normally not decided within the Makefile, but rather by a configure script. That is, you have one source tree and two builds from it, the one build a debug build using debug flags (-O0, -ggdb) of your libraries (via -I, -L, possibly setting the rpath) and the other build being a production build using production flags and the normal environment.

A typical setup would look like:

```
svn co my_source_url source
mkdir debug production
( cd debug && ../source/configure DEBUG_OPTIONS; )
( cd production && ../source/configure PRODUCTION_OPTIONS; )
```

Comment: thanks, now those configure scripts make sense. However I really don't like to write bash scripts, it's too errorprone. I guess I now know why people use cmake, scons and all that :). Never really saw the point of it, except to make Makefiles suck less

Comment: @Blub: Don't write configure scripts by hand, let autoconf do that job for you. And it does a very portable job, cmake and scons can't do that. You can use autoconf without automake.

Comment: thiton, thanks for that suggestion. Now I have a problem. The GNU Buildsystem seems like a good choice if you are using make. However I'm not sure how it will play together with my current build system which I learned to love (which is not Make, but http://gittup.org/tup/). It looks like the GNU Buildsystem requires the use of Make in my toolchain.

Comment: @Blub: autoconf depends only on two assumptions: That the "make" implementation doesn't use @ characters in its syntax (tup doesn't) and that it understands "${FOO}" variable substitutions (no idea how tup does that).

Comment: thiton, tup has this syntax: $(CC)

Comment: @Blub: Fair enough. A little heresy: I don't think there are more than 10 tup users yet, so you might just ask the developer to also accept ${CC}. Doesn't break anything and helps much.

Answer (score 2):

If your customers do the compilation .. you need pkg-config

If your customers only execute .. 
You have a launcher shell script, which sets LD_LIBRARY_PATH properly and executes the binary.

Comment: the rpath is not the only thing that changes from development to deployment, so a simple launcher wouldn't do any good. (see my example about changed include paths). Also LD_LIBRARY_PATH is considered bad form.